# Apache Storm: What does the OutputCollector.fail() method do?

Tags: java, apache-storm

When using BaseRichBolt, what is the difference between

```
_collector.fail(tuple)
```

and

```
_collector.ack(tuple)
```

Does it act like a time out and so cause the tuple to be resent? Or does it simply discard the tuple. If So what is the difference between the fail method or using ack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ack()` does acknowledge a tuple, i.e., tells Storm that a tuple was successfully processed.

`fail()` fails a tuple, i.e., tells Storm that a tuple could not be processed successfully and thus Storm will re-try this tuple later on (i.e., the original source tuple(s) will be reprocessed at some point). It's basically a fail-fast mechanism -- if you do not acknowledge a tuple within it's timeout, it will fail, too.